# Custom error log in apache2

Tags: apache, logging, apache2

In apache log file I am getting long messages such as:

```
[Wed Feb 21 19:32:18.916451 2018] [:error] [pid 23919] [client 10.0.2.2:50156] Error Message...
```

How I can get custom log message like:

Format:[Time] [Message]

```
[19:32:18] Error Message....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put
`ErrorLogFormat "[%{c}t] %M"`
in apache config file (supposedly, /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)
Other formatting options you can find in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat